# Signs in definition of $\Delta$-complexes

Tags: algebraic-topology

In Hatcher's book nth chain group defined as free module with basis consist of n-symplexes in $\Delta$-structure. Consider some basis element in $\Delta_1(X)$:
$$\sigma:[v_0,v_1]\to X$$
Our simplex considered with orientation? So can i say that $[v_0,v_1] = -[v_1,v0]$? If i can then how to say it rigorously?.
I was thinking that i was familiar with $\Delta$-homology, but this occasion completely breaks that feeling..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for each simplex we need to fix an order of its vertices so that induced orders on subsimplexes will be according with order on big ones. The easiest way to do it is fixing a global order of all the vertices ($0$-simplexes); it works if each $n$-simplexes has all itself vertices different, but actually for define a $\Delta$-complex structure this is not necessary: for each map $\Delta^n\to X$ we can fix this order *in sourse*, where these vertices are still different.

Comment: So we fix not only orientation of $\Delta^n$, but order of vertexes and so $$[v_0,v_1,v_2]\neq[v_2,v_0,v_1]$$?

Comment: @user2715119, actually you can think of orientation as a sign of permutation on the vertices order. But you should remember that there may be several simplices with the same set of vertices (if you cut a circle in two points, for example), and you should fix own order/orientation on each of them.